# fullscreen for vlc in Awesome wm

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

is there a way to let awesome set vlc in full screen without displaying the menu and progress-bar? I already tried to do this using dbus, but this won´t work for vlc.

P.S.: the code I used for dbus is:

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.banshee \
      /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2        \
      org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Fullscreen True
```

But it seams to be a problem with mpris, I tested it with other players and it does not work. (CanSetFullscreen gives True)

Comment: Thanks. Are you talking about VLC's menu bar and progess bar? Why not set the default "minimal view mode" in VLC?

Comment: never used that modus, it is a good work around as long as I do not find a permanent solution, thanks @rpattiso

Answer (score 1):

**1**. Add a rule in your `rc.lua` file by adding to the `awful.rules.rules` table:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    { rule={ class='Vlc' }, properties={ fullscreen=true } },
    -- more rules ....
}
```

**2**.  In VLC go to **Tools > Preferences**, check "Start in minimal view mode", and click "Save".

**3**. Reload awesome

Now when you startup VLC, it will start in full screen with no interface showing.

Comment: windowed version with visible controls, like it works with the shortcuts of for example gnome.